# An ODE that is solved "apparently" correctly, but gives the wrong result

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I wanted to solve

\begin{equation}
y''+\frac{1}{x}y'=0
\end{equation}

and thought immediately about subsitution $y''=w'$,

\begin{equation}
w'+\frac{1}{x}w=0\\
\frac{w'}{w}=-\frac{1}{x}\\
\ln|w|=\frac{1}{x^2} \\
w=e^{\frac{1}{x^2}} 
\\ \text{make the back-substitution } w=y'\\
y'=Ce^{\frac{1}{x^2}} \\
y=Ce^{\frac{1}{x^2}}x-\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}\frac{1}{x}+D
\end{equation}

Although this procedure is correct, the answer is wrong.

Still, if I  do substitution but use integrating factor, I also get the wrong answer:

\begin{equation}
w'+\frac{1}{x}w=0\\ \text{integrating factor}: e^{\int\frac{1}{x}dx} \\
\bigg(w e^{e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}}\bigg)'=0\\
w e^{e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}}=C\\\text{make the back-substitution } w''=y'\\
y'=Ce^{\frac{1}{x^2}}\\
y=Ce^{\frac{1}{x^2}}x-\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}\frac{1}{x}+D
\end{equation}

So two right procedures, and two wrong answers.

Any hints ?

Thanks

Comment: Good question. Here are some formatting tips: You can use `\text` within equations to type in things like "then make the substitution..." etc. Remember to use `\ln` instead of just `ln`. (Oh, and $\operatorname{erf}$ is usually left all in lowercase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primitive or anti-derivative of $\frac1x$ is $\ln|x|$. It is the derivative that is $-\frac1{x^2}$.

Also note that $xy''+y'=(xy')'$.

Comment: Naturally, I forgot the morning coffee today...